# Regex text/number extraction

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Below is regex code for getting the number 6 from my tesetstr. How can i extract the string 'months' from teststr using regex ?

```
var teststr = '6 months';
var num = /(\d+)\s*month/;
var days = teststr.match(num)[1];        
console.log(days);
```

Comment: provide your column data type and one sample value

Comment: We can't help you unless you explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: `var num = /(\d+)\s*month/;` -> `.match(num)[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `(\d+)` matches *one or more digits capturing them into Group 1* (note you are not using the group at all, so, it is redundant).

You seem to want to only match digits before a space + "month". Use the following regex:

```
var num = /(\d+)\s*month/;
```

and then access the captured value with

```
var days = ($('#infra_time_threshold').text()).match(num)[1] * 30;
                                                         ^^^
```

Alternatively, you could use a lookahead right after `\d+`:

```
var num = /\d+(?=\s*month)/;
```

and then just use your `.match(num)[0]` since Group 0 value will be the whole match.

**NOTE**: You might want to add a *null* check before accessing the 0th or 1st index of the `match` object.